# Oracle WHERE clause throwing ora-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12.2

I am running into the following error when I run the below SQL

> FuncTwo(ParamOne, ParamTwo)
> InnedColTwo,
> *
>
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large
> ORA-06512: at "Schema.FuncTwo", line 89

```
SELECT 
    C.UID AS ColOne,
    TO_NUMBER(C.ColTwo) AS ColTwo
FROM (
        SELECT
            B.UID,
            TO_NUMBER(B.MiddleColTwo) AS OuterColTwo
        FROM (
                SELECT 
                    A.UID,
                    CASE
                        WHEN (InnerColThree >= '54.6' AND InnerColThree <= '54.9') OR InnerColThree = '0' THEN 99
                        ELSE TO_NUMBER(InnerColTwo, '99.9')
                    END AS MiddleColTwo
                FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            UID,
                            FuncTwo(ParamOne, ParamTwo) InnerColTwo,
                            FuncThree(ParamOne, ParamTwo) InnerColThree
                        FROM
                            -- SOME STUFF
                        WHERE
                            -- SOME STUFF
                        UNION
                            SELECT 
                                UID,
                                FuncTwo(ParamOne, ParamTwo) AS InnerColTwo,
                                FuncThree(ParamOne, ParamTwo) AS InnerColThree
                            FROM 
                                -- SOME STUFF ...
                            WHERE 
                                -- SOME STUFF ...
                    ) A
            ) B
        WHERE B.ColTwo > 0 --Works when commented out. Throws error when uncommented.
    ) C;
```

But when I comment out `WHERE B.ColTwo > 0` The query works. I have tried assigning number formatting to all ColTwo values with TO_NUMBER() but nothing helped.

I dont understand why the query resolves when the middle query where clause is commented out, but fails when it is uncommented.

All values for that column resolve to between 0 and 99 with no decimals or negative values or values larger than 99.

Can someone assist me in resolving this?

Comment: You're missing open parens for both B and C and/or closed where you should not have. Row 29 is one example of a wrong closing. Check out rows 24, 26 and 35 to see why you have parens. Remove the parens in rows 24, 26 and 35, then remove the extra close in row 29.

Comment: @Isolated corrected parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Add this in where clause
`Where TO_NUMBER(B.MiddleColTwo) > 0`

Comment: If it's Oracle version 12 or later, then, to be certain:  TO_NUMBER(B.MiddleColTwo default null on conversion error) > 0

Comment: @Bogdan Dincescu unfortunately your suggestions didnt work. Resulted in the same error.

Comment: @XmalevolentX  what is the datatype of this column ? And why you are converting values to number in the else part (case statement).  ELSE TO_NUMBER(InnerColTwo, '99.9').
Take only the B table and query it alone. I believe u will receive an error due to this number conversion.